# Android app lifecycle engine library

Tags: android, lifecycle

For a project, I need something like a generic flexible lifecycle engine. What I mean is, I should be able to register a number of components with it. The components should be triggered on different app/activity lifecycle events.

For example:

- component A reacts to onStart(), onStop() and onDestroy()
- component B
  reacts to onStart() and onPause()

In addition components should be able to react to other components/events.

For example:

- component C gets triggered when components A and B have finished a specific task

Before I start to write something myself, I wanted to check if there is already a library out there that can do such things.

Comment: Well, OSGi comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom Application class extending Android `Application` class. Next, you can create and register [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html). After that, you can implement your logic inside the callbacks.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

   @Override
   public void onCreate () {
      super.onCreate();
      registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks());
   }

   private static final class MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

      public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
         Log.e("","onActivityCreated:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
      }

      public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
         Log.e("","onActivityDestroyed:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
      }

      public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
         Log.e("","onActivityPaused:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
      }

      public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
         Log.e("","onActivityResumed:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
      }

      public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
         Log.e("","onActivitySaveInstanceState:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
      }

      public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
         Log.e("","onActivityStarted:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
      }

      public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
         Log.e("","onActivityStopped:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That is actually pretty interesting. Two problems though: 1. it requires min android 14 and 2. it's no solution to the more complicated part of the question (the reacting to other component events)

Comment: Android 14 = Android 4.0.3. If you set min sdk to this version you'll still reach a lot of users, because Android 4 is commonly used version of this OS. With ActivityLifeCycleCallbacks, you can solve first problem (component A reacts on a specific event in an activity in general or inside a specific activity). I think, your second problem can be solved with RxJava. I don't know details of your task, but I suppose you can start at such point.